# Searching for 3D cad AI synthesis project (New CAD file form two similar CAD model)

Tags: image-generation

I saw this post: [Google AI generates images of 3D models with realistic lighting and reflections](https://venturebeat.com/2018/12/04/google-ai-generates-images-of-3d-models-with-realistic-lighting-and-reflections/).

[image]

Is there any project to test this capability for combining two 3d cad files of a similar model and get a new combined model as shown (Hoogle AI ...)? I would like to use software such as Blender, SolidWorks or some project via Google Colab (testable without the need to install any software).

Comment: What do you mean by "project"? Do you mean a library? Do you mean a model?  If you are looking for a library, this question seems to be off-topic. Please, edit your post to clarify that.

Comment: I am searching one project which is a combination of model and ... which I could test it and use for achieving one new 3d model based of two input 3d cad files (by AI Algorithms like GAN or ...)